# How can we evaluate a Gaussian in an intensity of an Image?

Tags: matlab

The section *4.3.1* of [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1155/2010/680429) says that:

> (iv) g(pi, ds) is a Gaussian function, evaluated in p1, with a peak in correspondence with the detected scratch direction ds and a constant standard deviation;

[image]

If `pI` is any pixel/intensity on this image, and `dS` is the `(rho, theta)` of that line in the Hough Space, which one of the following is the correct implementation of `gaussC()`?

**My first proposal:**

```
function val = gaussC(pI, sigma, dS)
    x = pI(1);
    y = pI(2);
    rho = dS(1);
    theta = dS(2);
    exponent = ((x-rho).^2 + (y-theta).^2)./(2*sigma);
    val = (exp(-exponent)); 
end
```

**My second proposal:**

```
I = gray_imread('Scratch1.png');

dimesnsion = 5;
sigma = 1;
pI = [22, 114];
dS = [-108, -80];

J = get_matrix_from_image(I, pI, dimension);
var = normpdf(J(:), dS(2), sigma);
```

**get_matrix_from_image.m**

```
function mat = get_matrix_from_image(input_image, ctr_point, dimension)
    [height, width] = size(input_image);
    col_count = width;
    row_count = height;
    xxx = col_count;
    yyy = row_count;

    if(ctr_point(1) < 1 && ctr_point(2) < 1)
        mat = zeros(dimension, dimension);
    else    
        x = ctr_point(1);
        y = ctr_point(2);

        start_x = x - floor(dimension/2);
        end_x = start_x + dimension - 1;        
        
        start_y = y - floor(dimension/2);    
        end_y = start_y + dimension - 1;

        if(start_x > xxx || end_x>xxx || start_y > yyy || end_y>yyy || ...
           start_x < 1 || end_x<1 || start_y <1 || end_y<1)
             mat = zeros(dimension, dimension);
        else
            mat = input_image(start_x:end_x, start_y:end_y);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 17):

Not quite. Basically you are manually coding formula (9) from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html). Then:

```
    ...
    exponent = ((x-rho).^2 + (y-theta).^2)./(2*sigma^2); % sigma is also squared
    val = exp(-exponent); % superfluous bracket removed
    val = val./(2*pi*sigma^2); % you also forgot the denominator part
end
```

Of course you could write the whole thing a bit more efficient. But unless you actually want to use this formula on a lot of data I would keep it like this (it's very readable).

If you value performance, just use the built in function:

```
val = normpdf(pI,dS,sigma)
```

For new readers of this question: The OP reopened this questions after editing it heavily, completely changing the nature of the question. Therefore this answer now seems a bit off.

Comment: what is the difference between `pI` and `pIk` ?

Comment: `pi` = the single i-th pixel of column k. `pIk` = a small matrix centred around p_i

Comment: I thought, `k` is the column of the entire image.

Comment: "ci is the "local" correlation value, computed between two windows, centered, respectively, in the last included point ps for the previous column, and in the candidate point pi of the column k." would make no sense then

Comment: The question is restored to original form that you have initially answered.

Comment: Your solution radiates some degree of doubt. `normpdf(pI,dS,sigma)` should serve our purpose.  `normpdf(x,mean,sigma)` accepts three arguments. Where `x` is a vector, `mean` and `sigma` are self-explanatory. In our case, `pI` should be that vector. That is, a vector of intensities. So, my question is, **which one is that vector of intensities in our problem?**

Comment: According to our problem, *peak of the gaussian should be in correspondence with direction `dS`*. **How are we accommodating this idea in `normpdf(pI,dS,sigma)`?**

Comment: honestly I really don't care anymore. The content of this question changes faster than the wind. I'd recommend checking out codementor or to look for a real world person who can help you (e.g. math student with coding skills or vice versa, remote sensing geographers, etc.).

Answer (score 10):

Your code is the incorrect implementation of the PDF of the normal distribution. The PDF of the normal distribution is:

[image]

IMO If `pI` is defined by `x` and `y`, i.e. `pI(x,y)`, and `dS` is defined by `rho` and `theta`, i.e. `dS(rho,theta)` then you cannot simply subtract `rho` from `x` and `theta` from `y` . You have to convert one of them to the other. In my code, I have converted `dS(rho,theta)` to `dS(x,y)` and then used it as `μ` in the formula of PDF.

Furthermore, I think `pI` would be a matrix of 5 rows and 2 columns (5 pixels with x and y values) saying this on the basis of the following figure which is *Figure 6* of the linked research:

[image]

Now coming to the statement,

> *g(p<sub>i</sub> , d<sub>s</sub>) is a Gaussian function, evaluated
>   in p<sub>i</sub>, with a peak in correspondence with the detected
>   scratch direction d<sub>s</sub> and a constant standard deviation.*

IMO The author/s of the paper suggest/s to take 5 pixels, calculate PDF and find where the peak is.

Based on my understanding, its implementation should be:

```
function val = gaussC(pI,dS,sigma)
    x = pI(:,1);    %x values of all pixels
    y = pI(:,2);    %y values of all pixels
    rho = dS(1);
    theta = dS(2);
    %Converting polar coordinates to rectangular coordinates to get mean value 
    %in x and y direction
    exponent = [(x-rho*cos(theta)).^2 + (y-rho*sin(theta)).^2]./(2*sigma^2);  
    val = exp(-exponent)./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi));
end
```

After calculating the PDF, find the peak value.

Comment: In other words, find the PDF for each of the five pixels and check which gives the maximum value

Comment: @anonymous that attitude wont really help you get help from people that are volunteering their time.